# Computation of DC motor parameters

Tags: motor, dc-motor, electromagnetism

How does one compute DC motor parameters instead of measure? Example: inductance, backemf,torque?

Would one use a EM simulator or is there another way?

Comment: Too vague. But if you have adequate data you can compute some parameters from other parameters in the datasheet plus the laws of physics.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the parameters are *relatively* simple to calculate but others not so. In any event, to calculate the parameters rather than measure them will require a lot of other measurements instead.
For example, the dc resistance, important for the speed regulation of a brushed (?) DC motor, will require knowing the length of the wire in the windings. So would need the relevant rotor dimensions to calculate the dc resistance. Torque will require knowledge of the rate of change of the inductance with respect to the rate of change of the rotational position (ie angular velocity).
It really would be easier just to measure the things. Why do you want to calculate these parameters instead of measuring them?
S.

Comment: Thanks, it appears ansys has a motor design simulation tool which I will read about. It looks like EM software is used but it's not the typical one for radiation/rf.